# How to reset Discord.OptionSelect in Python Pycord?

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

I am trying to implement a "Back" button that will return to the previous dropdown.
I am using Pycord.

I have a dropdown with options to pick different food categories, after you pick a category, the dropdown menu changes to a new dropdown where see items in that category.
In addition, you have a "Back" button that should get you to the previous dropdown.

At the moment I get `In components.0.components.0.options.1: The specified option value is already used` Error, after I click the back button and click the same category again.

Here is where I recreate the issue, first I run the slash command `/shop` and I click the "Meats" category

[image]

Then I get to a new dropdown and I click the "Back" Button:

[image]

I get to the original dropdown.
and if I click the "Meats" cateogry again it crushes.

[image]

**main.py**

```
import discord
from example1 import CategoryView

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.command()
async def shop(ctx):
    await ctx.respond("Choose a category from the dropdown below! ✨", view=CategoryView())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")

bot.run("TOKEN")
```

**example1.py**

```
import discord
from example2 import CategoryPriceView

class CategoryView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder = "Choose a food category!",
        min_values = 1,
        max_values = 1,
        options = [
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Meats",
                emoji=''
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Salads",
                emoji=''
            )
        ]
    )
    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction): 
        category = select.values[0]
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Choose your item!", view=CategoryPriceView(category, self))
```

**example2.py**

```
import discord

options = []

class CategoryPriceView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, category, father):
        super().__init__()
        global options
        self.category = category
        self.father = father

        if self.category == 'Meats':
            options.append(discord.SelectOption(label='Steak', description="Price: 40$"))

        elif self.category == 'Salads':
            options.append(discord.SelectOption(label='Greek Salad', description="Price: 30$"))

    @discord.ui.button(label="Back", row=1, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple) 
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Choose a category from the dropdown below! ✨", view=self.father)

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder = "Choose an item!",
        min_values = 1,
        max_values = 1,
        options = options
    )


    async def select_callback(self, select, interaction):
        item = select.values[0]
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"You chose {item}! ", view=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: My answer was completely wrong. Edited to provide actual answer.

The issue is the `global options`. Every time you select an option from the original `CategoryView`, you're creating a new instance of `CategoryPriceView` and adding to `options`. As `options` is global and never gets cleared - there are duplicates in there - hence the **duplicate value** error. You can resolve this by subclassing `Select` and creating a custom `CategoryPriceSelect` that has the options logic you want. See below.

```py
# example2.py

import discord


class CategoryPriceSelect(discord.ui.Select):
    def __init__(self, category: str) -> None:
        options = []
        if category == 'Meats':
            options.append(discord.SelectOption(label='Steak', description="Price: 40$"))
        elif category == 'Salads':
            options.append(discord.SelectOption(label='Greek Salad', description="Price: 30$"))

        super().__init__(
            placeholder="Choose an item!",
            min_values=1,
            max_values=1,
            options=options
        )

    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        item = self.values[0]
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content=f"You chose {item}! ", view=None)


class CategoryPriceView(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, category, father):
        super().__init__()
        self.category = category
        self.father = father
        select = CategoryPriceSelect(self.category)
        self.add_item(select)

    @discord.ui.button(label="Back", row=1, style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple) 
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.edit_message(content="Choose a category from the dropdown below! ✨", view=self.father)
```

I've tested this and this works now without throwing the error and I believe this has your desired functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however it didn't solve the problem,
This caused that you wouldn't be able to repick the same option again, if you pick the "Salads" option and then go back to pick the "Meats" option, you still get the same error message.

In addition, I would like to instantiate a new instance but I can't because I already imported `CategoryPriceView` from `CategoryView` and that can't work the opposite as it will cause `circular import error`

Comment: Yeah you're right, you wouldn't be able to chose the same option again. Perhaps it's worth considering a different approach? When I do multiple select forms in discord, I edit the original message and add a new select alongside the existing one. And when the user changes one of the earlier ones, the options change automatically in the following. And then a `submit` button to submit all the options (assuming that they have selected items for each select).

Comment: The circular imports is solvable though - either place those classes in the same file and have a `categoryviews.py` type file. _Or_, just use `import x` and then `x.CategoryView()` rather than using `from x import CategoryView`. If that makes sense.

Comment: Got you, I tried the `x.CategoryView()` solution, but it showed the same error. I didn't completely understand your first solution, don't you describe what I did?

Comment: I realised I messed up - my bad. The actual error is caused by a different issue - I have rewritten my answer. Hope that helps!